# Accidentically remove grant privileges for root MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I accidentically removed grant from the user_accounts tab (privileges) for root account

I have this extra account backend_dev_team

[image]

Now edit privileges clickable link is missing can I undo it?

**UPDATE**

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'root'@'localhost'; but gave me error access denied, I entered this using backend_dev_team and root account`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I login using SSH and use this command

`sudo -i`

This will allow you to login as root

and from there

`mysql -u backend_dev_team -p` (this is your account who has grant option)

and type this

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

`flush privileges`

refresh phpmyadmin

and you will see edit privileges clickable link.

and that's it! Thanks

Comment: You don't need `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` here see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36464093/2716218